# Checking how many files there are of a certain type in a directory and all sub-directories

Tags: linux, windows, shell, find

I want to find how many `.py` files I have in my `GarlicSim` directory and all its sub-directories. How do I do that? Either Windows or Linux is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows platforms:

```
dir /s *.py
```

Answer (score 5):

On Linux:

```
find /path/to/GarlicSim -type f -name "*.py" | wc -l
```

Comment: This command works on any unix/POSIX system, not just Linux. It even works on Windows provided you have any unix/POSIX compatibility package installed (Services For Unix, Cygwin, msys, GNUwin32, UWIN, ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
find $DIR -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c  | sort -rn
```

Comment: For the unix-unitiated: this command lists the number of files under `$DIR` for each extension; the output is sorted by decreasing count.